# Does querying Win32_Product class trigger msi repairs

Tags: wmi-query

MSDN states that Win32_product Class is not query optimized. The process also initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying and repairing the install.I tried Querying the class with a Select query and tampered a sample msi package by deleting some installed files, but no repair was triggered. The event log showed msi reconfiguration but there was no repair action. Does querying the class actually trigger repair in case an installed program is corrupted, and if it does then do we have any examples to support this?

Comment: Win32_Product is evil. It can result in all MSI applications being "reconfigured": https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/

Answer (score 2):

WMI queries are too slow. Querying Installer.ProductInfo can get you results in 0.1 seconds, which is 200 times faster than WMI on my machine.

```
Dim msi : Set msi = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
On Error Resume Next
Dim version : version = msi.ProductInfo("{ProductCode}", "VersionString")
Dim installed : installed = ( Err.Number = 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to the source? I know win32_product is slow because it's not query optimized, and small queries take about 1 minute for me. If it did a repair on every msi installed on my system (371 according to a "quick" check with Powershell), I'm positive it would take much longer.

There are methods in that class that can trigger a repair. I use it after installing a specific application whose shortcuts are always mysteriously missing on install. Calling Reinstall(9) takes care of that for me. It's documented here:
[Win32_Product Class (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)